# emberjs component doesn't rerender component to update fullcalendar

Tags: ember.js, fullcalendar, ember-cli, ember-router, ember-components

I am building a calendar app using emberjs and Jquery fullcalendar. The fullcalendar is rendered via emberjs component. However, when a new event is created via a form and the route refresh() method called, the component doesn't rerender or redraw itself. Therefore to see the new event on fullcalendar, I have to manually refresh the page. How can I get the component to rerender when a new event is created. I have tried with event route and template before using events/index route and template.

app/event/templates/index.hbs

```
 {{cal-event model=model event=model refreshModel='refreshModel'}}
```

app/routes/events/index.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route':
export default Route.extend({
   model(){
     let model = this.get('store').findAll('event', {reload: true});
     return model;
   },

   actions: {
     refreshModel(data) {
       let e = data.get('start');
       let d = data.get('description');
       let f = data.get('finish');
       let event = this.get('store').createRecord('event', {description: d, start: e, finish: f})

       event.save().then((e) => {
         this.refresh(); 
         this.transitionTo("events")
       }, function(e) {
         console.log("event error", e)
       })   
     }
   }
 });
```

app/components/cal-event.js

```
 import Component from '@ember/component';
 import EmberObject, { computed, observer } from '@ember/object';
 export default Component.extend({
   event: '',

   didUpdateAttrs(data) {
     console.log('didUpdatedAttrs called', data);
   },

   didRender() {
     console.log('didRender');
   },

   didInsertElement() {
     this._super(...arguments);
     this.$().attr('contenteditable', true);
     return this.$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
       events: this.eventJSON(),
       defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
     });
   },

   eventJSON() {
     return this.get('model').map(function(event) {
      return event.get('toJSON');
     });
   },

   getnewEvent: computed('newEvent', function(){
     console.log('getnewEvent',  this.get('newEvent'));
   }),

   modelChanged: Ember.observer('model', function(){
     console.log("model changed!");
   }), 

  eventsDidChange: Ember.observer('model.[]', function() {
    this.$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
      events: this.eventJSON,
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
    });
  }),

   actions: {
     createEvent: function(param) {
       this.sendAction('refreshModel', param);
     }
   }
 });
```

Update.

I added didUpdateAttrs and didRender().

update 2

I got another suggestion from bendemboski through slack that I should try adding an observer on the model array as in Ember.observer('model.[]'). It didn't work, component is not rerendered and fullcalendar doesn't show the new event.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option1: Your current observer solution will work, mistake is `eventsDidChange` observer function  you missed to call `this.eventJSON()`

Option2.You want to draw the calendar again whenever there is change in model data, for that you can do rendering in `didRender` method. You don't need observer at all.

Notes:

1.Dont expect `getnewEvent` computed property will be called, it will be called only when you request for it thourgh `get` or in template. currently it looks its not returning the value. Remember computed property always should return the value.  but this is not related to your problem.

2.In events/index.js,

```
this.refresh(); 
 this.transitionTo("events")
```

Both above will do the same thing, I think in your case you dont need to call both method, since your model hook is using the findAll so it will return live record array so it will be automatically be updated. due to that your `cal-event` component will call [rerendering methods](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_on-re-render).

Comment: Thanks. Just to broaden my knowledge.  Do you know why it still doesn't work if I call the component ie **{{cal-event model=model event=model refreshModel='refreshModel'}} ** from **events.hbs** instead of **events/index.hbs** & the model loaded from **events route**.  the form template is at **events/new**.  through logging I can see that when a new record is created, the component is never called when it is in **events.hbs** & the new data is not passed to it. But if I add the component to **events/index** & still data from **events route** everything still works. fails if form in index.hbs

Comment: I created sample twiddle for demonstration - you can play with typing URL like `/events` and `/events/new` watch out console what are all model hook is called. https://ember-twiddle.com/1adc678b9558678743f44b7575536742?openFiles=router.js%2C

Comment: There is ember-diagonal from AlexSpeller. you can use that for better understanding of the routes. I [created sample for you](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/events?routesInput=this.route(%27events%27%2C%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20this.route(%27index%27)%3B%0A%20%20this.route(%27new%27)%3B%20%20%0A%7D)%3B ) Most importantly select Tree view and click on node and right side you can see all corresponding routes and templates and its hook method calling order.